# SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In the database i have id as a primary key and this 8 elements,this is my whole code and ofc i have names in the form 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```php
<?php
    require_once 'dbh.php';

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST['име'];
        $lastname = $_POST['презиме'];
        $company = $_POST['компанија'];
        $email =$_POST['емаил'];
        $number =$_POST['број'];
        $workers= $_POST['employees'];
        $sectors= $_POST['sector'];
        $text=$_POST['порака'];

        $form= [
            "име" => $name,
            "презиме" => $lastname, 
            "компанија" => $company, 
            "емаил" => $email, 
            "број" => $number, 
            "employees"=> $workers, 
            "sector" => $sectors, 
            "порака" => $text      
        ];

        $sql= "INSERT INTO form (name,lastname,company,email,number,workers,sector,text)
        VALUES (:име,:презиме,:компанија,:емаил,:број,:employees,:sector,:порака)";        

        try {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(':име',$name);
            $statement->bindValue(':презиме',$lastname);
            $statement->bindValue(':компанија',$company);
            $statement->bindValue(':емаил',$email);
            $statement->bindValue(':број',$number);
            $statement->bindValue(':employees',$workers);
            $statement->bindValue(':sector',$sectors);
            $statement->bindValue(':порака',$text);
            $statement->execute();
            $form= $pdo->lastInsertId();
            header("location: register.php?id=$form");
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `6poj` to something that starts with a letter.

I had something like this happen before and I'm pretty sure if you're going to use strings as keys for an array they're not supposed to start with a number, in this case `6poj`. I think what ends up happening is its read as 6 instead, causing the sixth element to get set twice, leaving only 7 items in the array.

Comment: Still the same :(